# Xcode tableview scroll issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, scroll

I'm writing an IOS app that will create a Football (soccer) Cup. I specify the name of the Cup, and the number of teams. Then when they hit a button called 'Continue' I present a Tableview of all the teams, and turn on multiple selection. Everything is fine so far. If the number of teams is 2 or 4, it works OK, but if I specify 8 or more, I need to scroll on the tableView. Then I get the error -

```
teamNames.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!) - Thread 1 EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10093c624)
```

I don't understand why scrolling the names in the tableview (there are 7 teams viewable by default, so I need to scroll to get to the 8th) would cause a problem. I thought tableviews were specifically designed to scroll.

Also, in the console area, I get:

warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

Here's the code for the tableview:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cupTeam.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text! = cupTeam [indexPath.row].name!
    return cell
}
```

Thanks for any insight into my tableview problem

Here's the loop that the code that caused the error is in:

```
   for indexPath in selectedIndexPaths! {
        let cell = teamTable.cellForRow (at: indexPath)
        teamNames.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)
    }
```

Comment: 1. Where is the code that actually causes your issue? 2. Please stop all of the bad uses of `!`. Learning how to properly work with optionals is a key skill needed by any Swift developer.

Comment: Sorry. Here's the loop:  `for indexPath in selectedIndexPaths! {
            let cell = teamTable.cellForRow (at: indexPath)
            teamNames.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)
        }`

Comment: Update your question. Please don't post code in comments.

Comment: Sorry about that. Still getting used to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedIndexPaths` would return all the selected indexPaths regardless of whether they are visible or not. When you call

```
let cell = teamTable.cellForRow (at: indexPath)
```

it will return nil if the cell is not visible on screen. Then you force unwrap it to get the value and it crashes. One easy fix is to use `if let`

```
for indexPath in selectedIndexPaths! {
    if let cell = teamTable.cellForRow (at: indexPath) {
        teamNames.append((cell.textLabel?.text)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the cell is one of those selected, and not now on the screen (because it scrolled off), how do I retrieve it? I thought that selectedIndexPaths from multiple selection gave a complete good list of all those selected.

Comment: It does. but the line `let cell = teamTable.cellForRow (at: indexPath)` only works for cells that are visible on the screen. When the cells scroll off the screen, the cells themselves are reused and filled with the new data. When you give it an indexPath that is not visible anymore, it will return nil. Hence the crash. If you want a list of all the selected cells, you'll have to maintain an array of values and use that array instead of trying to access `let cell = teamTable.cellForRow (at: indexPath)` and getting the value out of cell

Comment: Ahh. I see. So the array I used to populate the Table can be used with selectedIndexPath! to get the team names. OK. I'll try that.

Comment: Glad to be of help